# Differentiating an integral with two functions

Tags: integration, derivatives, improper-integrals

How can I differentiate the following with respect to x? $$h(x) = \int_a^\infty f(x,a)g(x,a)da$$
that is: 
$$d\frac{f(x)}{dx} = \frac d{dx}\left(\int_a^\infty f(x,a)g(x,a)da\right)$$

I'm wondering if I can just treat $f(x,a)g(x,a)$ as $h(x,a)$ and use Liebniz's integral rule. If that is a good approach, then I think I get the following: 
$$\frac d{dx}\left(\int_a^\infty h(x,a)da\right)$$ 
and applying the rule,
$$= \int_a^\infty \frac{\partial h(x,a)}{\partial x}da$$
If this is correct, can I proceed further to put this in terms of $f(x,a)$ and $g(x,a)$ again?

Note that $$\lim\limits_{a \to \infty} f(x) = 0$$
also note 
$$h(x,a) = f(x,a)*g(x,a)$$

Edits: initially I called the function $f(x)$ but corrected it to $h(x)$

Comment: Note I am very bad at math, so I don't even know if $f(x,a)g(x,a) -> h(x,a)$

Comment: Yes this is correct. The integrand would become $f_x(x,a)g(x,a)+f(x,a)g_x(x,a)$ where $f_x$ and $g_x$ are partial derivatives of the functions with respect to $x$.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterForeman I may have mis-written the initial formula... it should not be $f(x)$ instead it should be $h(x)$... does that affect things, though? See my edits and also note $h(x,a) = f(x,a)*g(x,a)$

Comment: Your use of the same letter to denote different functions is a little confusing but it doesn't change the answer.